# Is there a way I can pass in arguments to $http as part of an object?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following call:

```
     $scope.retrieve = function () {

         $resource('/api/Test/Retrieve')
             .query({
                 subjectId: $scope.config.subjectId,
                 examId: $scope.config.examId,
                 userId: $scope.config.createdById
             },
             function (result) {
                 $scope.grid.data = angular.copy(result);
             },
          function () {
              $scope.grid.data = null;
          });
     };
```

Is there a way that I could pass in the arguments through an object like this and use an $http call instead of a $resource.  Also how could I move the success and error code blocks to there own functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below should work for posting with data.

```
$http.post("/api/Test/Retrieve", {
               subjectId:$scope.config.subjectId,
               examId:$scope.config.examId,
               userId:$scope.config.createdById
             }).success(
             function(res){
               //Some success handler here
             }).error(
             function(res){
               //Some error handler here
             });
```

There are lots of details you may want to include, if you need a GET with parameters check out the config parameter and it's properties:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

```
//Same sample with handler functions moved out for ease of reading etc.

var successFunction = function(res){
}
var errorFunction = function(res) {
}
var params = {
               subjectId:$scope.config.subjectId,
               examId:$scope.config.examId,
               userId:$scope.config.createdById
             };

$http.post("/api/Test/Retrieve", params).
  success(successFunction).
  error(errorFunction);
```

Comment: That's great. I will do it like that.  My success handler is really long. How can I move the success and error codes into functions and then just call those ?

Comment: just as you say it really, you can just name the functions somewhere in advance of using them (believe variable hoisting will sort of help here automatically too), I'll modify my answer a bit.